# text justification characters in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Problem with excel 2013, every time I type anything in an empty cell after I come back to it it shows alignment characters in the formula bar before the cell contents (see image below).

Is there any way that I can get rid of these characters?

Please note that when I set `a1` to left alignment I have `'` then when I make it center I get `^` and when I make it right justified I get `"`.

The text justification affects the 1st character in the formula bar:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb3Sb.png]

Comment: It does this on a new, blank Sheet (in a new, blank Workbook)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the **Lotus compatibility options** in Excel Options *(Advanced)*

I believe that in Lotus the prefix characters were used to control alignment and auto-supplying them was used to facilitate compatibility.

Even without enforcing compatibility, Excel will still accept a leading **single quote** as a method to tell Excel to treat typed input as *Text*

Comment: Jst to note. You can always edit your own posts. It might help to say why this solves the problem since its not quite intuitive

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  You are correct.............I re-Posted in error....I should have edited the original answer.............I believe that in *Lotus* the prefix characters were used to control alignment and auto-supplying them was used to facilitate compatibility.